# Access SQL - Get last available value

Tags: sql, ms-access, outer-join

scenario:

Table 1 (dates)

```
01/01/12
02/01/12
```

Table 2 (counts)

```
01/01/12 | Item 1 | 10
01/01/12 | Item 2 | 15
03/01/12 | Item 1 | 5
```

1. I have to join the two tables, not leaving gaps in dates:
   An OUTER JOIN did the trick.
2. I want to have the last available number if that date is missing in Table 2.
   E.g.

```sql
02/01/12 | Item 1 | 10
02/01/12 | Item 2 | 15
```

I am struggling on this. Any hints?

Comment: Could you please update your post with the SQL query that you are currently using?

Comment: SELECT Table1.Date, Table2.Item, Table2.Qty  FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Date = Table2.Date

Comment: Update your question please

Answer (score 0):

A query can transform, and join data, but it cannot generate new data (rows) that were not there to begin with. In your case if the 02/01/12 data row is missing you aren't going to be able to create rows on the fly to fill in the gaps in your query results.

To fix, create a 3rd table or sub-query that contains all of the lookup date segments that you need in your results, and include that in your outer join on the outer query.

Comment: Not sure I got it. My query returns the 02/01/12 row, but it obviously has two empty columns for Item and quantity. My target is having those columns filled with last available quantity per item.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so we have [Table1]

```
Date      
----------
2013-01-01
2013-02-01
2013-03-01
```

and [Table2]

```
Date        Item    Qty
----------  ------  ---
2013-01-01  Item 1   10
2013-01-01  Item 2   15
2013-03-01  Item 1    5
```

We can start by creating a saved query in Access named [DesiredRows] to give us the complete set of Date/Item values we want to see:

```sql
SELECT Table1.Date, i.Item
FROM
    Table1,
    (SELECT DISTINCT Item FROM Table2) AS i
```

...returning

```
Date        Item  
----------  ------
2013-01-01  Item 1
2013-02-01  Item 1
2013-03-01  Item 1
2013-01-01  Item 2
2013-02-01  Item 2
2013-03-01  Item 2
```

Now we can use that query as part of a saved query named [LastAvailableDates] to give us the last available date in Table2 for each of those pairs

```sql
SELECT 
    DesiredRows.Date, 
    DesiredRows.Item, 
    MAX(Table2.Date) AS LastAvailableDate
FROM 
    DesiredRows 
    INNER JOIN 
    Table2 
        ON Table2.Item = DesiredRows.Item 
            AND Table2.Date <= DesiredRows.Date
GROUP BY DesiredRows.Date, DesiredRows.Item
```

...returning

```
Date        Item    LastAvailableDate
----------  ------  -----------------
2013-01-01  Item 1  2013-01-01       
2013-01-01  Item 2  2013-01-01       
2013-02-01  Item 1  2013-01-01       
2013-02-01  Item 2  2013-01-01       
2013-03-01  Item 1  2013-03-01       
2013-03-01  Item 2  2013-01-01
```

Finally, we can use *that* query in a query to retrieve the final results

```sql
SELECT 
    LastAvailableDates.Date, 
    LastAvailableDates.Item, 
    Table2.Qty
FROM 
    LastAvailableDates 
    INNER JOIN 
    Table2 
        ON Table2.Date = LastAvailableDates.LastAvailableDate 
            AND Table2.Item = LastAvailableDates.Item
```

...returning

```
Date        Item    Qty
----------  ------  ---
2013-01-01  Item 1   10
2013-01-01  Item 2   15
2013-02-01  Item 1   10
2013-02-01  Item 2   15
2013-03-01  Item 1    5
2013-03-01  Item 2   15
```

Comment: Great! With little tweaking it is exactly what I was after! Thanks mate!